# Angular Put Request to Change Boolean

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my Todolist App, I want to update the Boolean for True or False by clicking on the Todo.

In todolist.component.html:

```
<div class="todo-list">
    <label class="todo-input">
        <input (keyup.enter)="add(todoName.value); todoName.value=''" #todoName/>
    </label>
    <button (click)="add(todoName.value); todoName.value=''">add</button>
    <ul *ngFor="let todo of todos">
        <li class="finished-{{todo.completed}}">{{todo.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then here's my code in my todo.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

    private todosURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/todos/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
        return this.http.get<Todo[]>(this.todosURL)
    }

    addTodo(todo: Todo): Observable<Todo> {
        return this.http.post<Todo>(this.todosURL, todo, httpOptions).pipe(
            tap((todo: Todo) => this.log(`We ve added the to do with id=${todo.id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<Todo>('addTodo'))
        );
    }
}
```

and lastly, the code in my todolist.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTodos();
}

getTodos(): void {
    this.todoService.getTodos()
        .subscribe(todos => this.todos = todos);
}

add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) {
        return;
    }
    this.todoService.addTodo({name} as Todo)
        .subscribe(todo => {
            this.todos.push(todo);
        })
}
```

Most of it is copy and paste from the Heroes Angular Tutorial Page; but would love to see what I can do with Boolean calls

also, I did set my Completed Boolean in my Model as a String, I read somewhere that angular doesnt accept boolean as a proper type

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?  toggle value on click?

Comment: yes, sorry. i want to switch the boolean of true/false with a click